# OpenTk with f# issue ("namespace or module OpenTK)

Tags: .net, opengl, f#, opentk

I know f# with opentk is very translatable from c#, however my problem is slightly less obvious because of the fact that f# isn't incredibly popular as it is.

From writing

```
open OpenTK
```

right of the bat I get

```
The namespace or module 'OpenTK' is not defined
```

I also listed OpenTK in my references, so I'm not sure.

I did research, but as always there's going to be something that escaped my searches, so I thought that someone more knowledgeable in the first place might be of assistance.

If there's a better way or place to post this please let me know.

Comment: Use NuGet package for install

Comment: @FoggyFinder This worked. I think this is the easiest thing to do. If anyone has this issue in VS just go to PROJECTS > Manage NuGet Packages> search online packages for "OpenTK".

Answer (score 1):

This is an error that you get when you're missing a reference to a library where `OpenTK` is defined. There are two ways of adding references, depending on whetehr you're in a project or in a script file.

**Script file** - if you're working in a `.fsx` file, you need to reference assemblies using the `#r` command. I wrote [a demo that does exactly this](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/tree/master/Talks%202014/DSL%20(NDC%20Oslo)/code/Functional3D) and builds a little 3D DSL. The file starts with:

```
#r "references/OpenTK.dll"
open OpenTK
```

**Project** - if you're inside a project than adding reference in Visual Studio should do the trick. If something goes wrong, check out the build log - if you were referencing incompatible version of the `dll` (e.g. for another version of .NET), you'd see a detailed error there.

Comment: I was in a f# console app project. And I added the reference, I don't know if I referenced the right folder exactly though. I think the "opentk is not defined" error was the only error, though I may be wrong. I'll check tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are also having this issue go to

```
PROJECTS > Manage NuGet Packages > Online > search "OpenTK".
```